# Keep alive solution for cron job

Tags: php, javascript, cron, wget

I have a hosted websolution and a script that update information backend for the site.

My webhost allows cron and I have made a script that wget's to every hour.

The script checks the db-table with posts to update for the oldest updated post and update that. In the end of the script I use javascript refresh to do the same procedure again this time with the second oldest updated post and so on until all posts are run through. If I open the script in my browser it works fine but when my host sets up the cron the script does not continue after the javascrpt refresh.

How can I solve this with another refresh solution that will work until the my statement stops it just by letting cron start the script?

(I changed to this solution from one where all posts were updated in one pageload but since it started to time out I went with this)

script.php

```
$limit=3600;       

//Select the oldest updated post

if($last_update<$update_to_limit){ //check if the post was updated during this run

        // Script that update the post and below the java refresh that repeats the script.

    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
                <!--
                window.location.href = "http://www.site.se/script.php"
                //-->
        </script>
    <?php
    }else{
        echo 'OK : All posts updated within the last : '.$limit.' s'; 
    }
```

Comment: Cron jobs will not execute javascript as they don't use a browser, they use command line.

Answer (score 1):

Wget will not run Javascript, if you open your code from the browser, it will of course run it, that is the reason of the difference.

I don't really suggest the method you're trying to use. If you really want, you can call `wget` again from PHP, use `cURL` or I guess even `header('Location..');`. But it would be much nicer to solve this problem in one turn.

If your code times out, I'd recheck the way that PHP code is written, and try to find a better solution, that is not so time-consuming. Afterwards: is the DB good enough, are the indexes set, etc. Or, if you cannot optimize it (or you do not want to), you can use [set_time_limit()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php).

*(One more thing: Java!=Javascript. If you want to shorten it, write js instead of java)*

Comment: I will try php header('location') and hope it works. The php.ini I cannot change unfortunately and the timed out code is oretty good I think but it involves fetching data from extarnal urls and multiple of those if I want to do it at once.

Comment: I dont think I am allowed since it is a hosted solution wiht a common php.ini

Comment: It is a command you can use in your code, you don't have to tweak the php.ini. They might have disabled it, so there's no other way but trying it :). It only changes the execution time for the specific script you're using it in.